# Django Ulrs matched path but still 404

Tags: django, django-models, django-views, django-templates, django-settings

I have a bug and not sure how to fix it, I've been writing an e-comm site and all of a sudden I'm getting a 404 page, Everything was working fine. The bug report tells me that the path matched the last one, but still getting 404. It's not only one app, it's all of them.  I just have no clue how to fix this.

Settings:

```py
from pathlib import Path
import environ
import os
import dj_database_url

env = environ.Env()
# read the .env file
environ.Env.read_env()

BASE_DIR = Path(__file__).resolve().parent.parent

SECRET_KEY = env('SECRET_KEY') 

DEBUG = True

ALLOWED_HOSTS = ['*']
TAX_RATE_PERCENTAGE = 23
FREE_DELIVERY_THRESHOLD = 200

# Application definition
INSTALLED_APPS = [
    'whitenoise.runserver_nostatic',
    'django.contrib.admin',
    'django.contrib.auth',
    'django.contrib.contenttypes',
    'django.contrib.sessions',
    'django.contrib.messages',
    'django.contrib.staticfiles',
    'django.contrib.sitemaps',
    'django.contrib.sites',
    'cloudinary_storage',
    'cloudinary',
    'allauth',
    'allauth.account',
    'allauth.socialaccount',
    'mathfilters',
    'crispy_forms',
    'ckeditor',
    
    'home',
    'boutique',
    'bag',
    'checkout',
    'profiles'

]

MIDDLEWARE = [
    'django.middleware.security.SecurityMiddleware',
    'whitenoise.middleware.WhiteNoiseMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.sessions.middleware.SessionMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.common.CommonMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.csrf.CsrfViewMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.auth.middleware.AuthenticationMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.messages.middleware.MessageMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.clickjacking.XFrameOptionsMiddleware',
]

ROOT_URLCONF = 'IMC.urls'

TEMPLATES = [
    {
        'BACKEND': 'django.template.backends.django.DjangoTemplates',
        'DIRS': [BASE_DIR / "templates"],
        'APP_DIRS': True,
        'OPTIONS': {
            'context_processors': [
                'django.template.context_processors.debug',
                'django.template.context_processors.request',
                'django.contrib.auth.context_processors.auth',
                'django.contrib.messages.context_processors.messages',
                'django.template.context_processors.media',
                'bag.contexts.bag_contents',
            ],
            'builtins': [
                'crispy_forms.templatetags.crispy_forms_tags',
                'crispy_forms.templatetags.crispy_forms_field',
            ]
        },
    },
]

AUTHENTICATION_BACKENDS = [

    # Needed to login by username in Django admin, regardless of `allauth`
    'django.contrib.auth.backends.ModelBackend',

    # `allauth` specific authentication methods, such as login by e-mail
    'allauth.account.auth_backends.AuthenticationBackend',

]

ACCOUNT_AUTHENTICATION_METHOD = "email"
ACCOUNT_EMAIL_REQUIRED = True
ACCOUNT_EMAIL_VERIFICATION = "None"
ACCOUNT_SIGNUP_EMAIL_ENTER_TWICE = False
ACCOUNT_USERNAME_MIN_LENGTH = 3
LOGIN_URL = '/accounts/login/'
LOGIN_REDIRECT_URL = '/'
ACCOUNT_LOGOUT_REDIRECT_URL = '/'

SITE_ID = 1

WSGI_APPLICATION = 'IMC.wsgi.application'

# Database
DATABASES = {
    'default': {
        'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.sqlite3',
        'NAME': BASE_DIR / 'db.sqlite3',
    }
}


# Password validation
# https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.2/ref/settings/#auth-password-validators

AUTH_PASSWORD_VALIDATORS = [
    {
        'NAME': 'django.contrib.auth.password_validation.UserAttributeSimilarityValidator',
    },
    {
        'NAME': 'django.contrib.auth.password_validation.MinimumLengthValidator',
    },
    {
        'NAME': 'django.contrib.auth.password_validation.CommonPasswordValidator',
    },
    {
        'NAME': 'django.contrib.auth.password_validation.NumericPasswordValidator',
    },
]


# Internationalization
# https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.2/topics/i18n/

LANGUAGE_CODE = 'en-us'

TIME_ZONE = 'UTC'

USE_I18N = True

USE_L10N = True

USE_TZ = True


# Static files (CSS, JavaScript, Images)
# https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.2/howto/static-files/

STATIC_URL = '/static/'
STATICFILES_DIRS = [BASE_DIR / "static"]
STATIC_ROOT = 'static_root'
# WHITENOISE - static storage
STATICFILES_STORAGE = 'whitenoise.storage.CompressedManifestStaticFilesStorage'

MEDIA_URL = '/media/'
# CLOUDINARY for media storage
DEFAULT_FILE_STORAGE = 'cloudinary_storage.storage.MediaCloudinaryStorage'


DEFAULT_AUTO_FIELD = 'django.db.models.BigAutoField'

CRISPY_TEMPLATE_PACK = 'bootstrap4'

CKEDITOR_CONFIGS = {
    'default': {
        'toolbar': 'full',
    },
}

# STRIPE
STRIPE_CURRENCY = 'eur'
if "DEV" in os.environ:
    STRIPE_PUBLIC_KEY = env('STRIPE_PUBLIC_KEY')
    STRIPE_SECRET_KEY = env('STRIPE_SECRET_KEY')
    STRIPE_WH_SECRET = env('STRIPE_WH_SECRET')

else:
    STRIPE_PUBLIC_KEY = os.environ.get('STRIPE_PUBLIC_KEY')
    STRIPE_SECRET_KEY = os.environ.get('STRIPE_SECRET_KEY')
    STRIPE_WH_SECRET = os.environ.get('STRIPE_WH_SECRET')

# SESSION_COOKIE_SECURE = True
# SECURE_BROWSER_XSS_FILTER = True
# SECURE_CONTENT_TYPE_NOSNIFF = True
# SECURE_HSTS_SECONDS = 3153600
# SECURE_REDIRECT_EXEMPT = []
# SECURE_SSL_REDIRECT = True
# SECURE_PROXY_SSL_HEADER = ('HTTP_X_FORWARDED_PROTO', 'https')

# EMAIL
EMAIL_USE_TLS = True
EMAIL_PORT = 587
EMAIL_HOST = 'smtp.gmail.com'
EMAIL_BACKEND = 'django.core.mail.backends.smtp.EmailBackend'
# EMAIL_BACKEND = 'django.core.mail.backends.console.EmailBackend'
EMAIL_HOST_USER = os.environ.get('EMAIL_HOST_USER')
EMAIL_HOST_PASSWORD = os.environ.get('EMAIL_HOST_PASSWORD')
NOTIFY_EMAIL = os.environ.get('NOTIFY_EMAIL')
DEFAULT_FROM_EMAIL = os.environ.get('EMAIL_HOST_USER')

# CLOUDINARY_CONFIG
if "DEV" in os.environ:
    CLOUDINARY_STORAGE = {
            'CLOUD_NAME': env('CLOUD_NAME'),
            'API_KEY': env('API_KEY'),
            'API_SECRET': env('API_SECRET'),
        }
else:
    CLOUDINARY_STORAGE = {
        'CLOUD_NAME': os.environ.get('CLOUD_NAME'),
        'API_KEY': os.environ.get('API_KEY'),
        'API_SECRET': os.environ.get('API_SECRET'),
    }
```

Root-URLS:

```py
from django.conf import settings
from django.conf.urls.static import static
from django.conf.urls import url
from django.contrib import admin
from django.contrib.staticfiles.storage import staticfiles_storage
from django.urls import path, include
from django.views.generic.base import RedirectView
from home.views import IndexView

urlpatterns = [
    path('', include('home.urls')),
    path('admin/', admin.site.urls),
    path('accounts/', include('allauth.urls')),
    path('boutique/', include('boutique.urls')),
    path('bag/', include('bag.urls', namespace='bag')),
    path('checkout/', include('checkout.urls', namespace='checkout')),
    path('profiles/', include('checkout.urls', namespace='profiles')),
        path('favicon.ico', RedirectView.as_view(
        url=staticfiles_storage.url('img/favicon.ico'))),
    url(r'^.*/$', IndexView.as_view())
]

if settings.DEBUG:
    urlpatterns += static(settings.MEDIA_URL,
                          document_root=settings.MEDIA_ROOT)
```

App-urls:

```py
from django.urls import path
from home.views import (
    ContactView, IndexView, 
    TermsView, GalleryView, 
    aboutview, PrivacyView
)

urlpatterns = [
    path('', IndexView.as_view(), name='home'),
    path('about/', aboutview, name='about'),
    path('gallery/', GalleryView.as_view(), name='gallery'),
    path('contact/',  ContactView.as_view(), name='contact'),
    path('terms/', TermsView.as_view(), name='terms'),
    path('privacy/',  PrivacyView.as_view(), name='privacy'),
]
```

APP-View:

```py
from django.conf import settings
from django.contrib import messages
from django.core.mail import send_mail
from django.shortcuts import reverse, render
from django.views import generic
from django.views.generic import TemplateView
from django.views.generic.list import ListView
from .forms import ContactForm
from boutique.models import Product
from .models import (About, Scarfs, Paintings,
                     ImageGallery, Home, PrivacyPolicy,
                     TermsConditions, Comment)

class IndexView(ListView):
    model = Home
    template_name = "home/index.html"
    context_object_name = "home"

    def get_context_data(self, **kwargs):
        comments = Comment.objects.all()
        context = super().get_context_data(**kwargs)
        context['comments'] = comments
        return context

def aboutview(request):
    feat_item = Product.objects.filter(feat_item=True)
    about = About.objects.all()
    scarfs = Scarfs.objects.all()
    paintings = Paintings.objects.all()
    context = {
        'feat_item': feat_item,
        'about': about,
        'scarfs': scarfs,
        'paintings': paintings,
    }
    return render(request, "home/about.html", context)

class GalleryView(ListView):
    model = ImageGallery
    template_name = "home/gallery.html"
    context_object_name = "images"

class TermsView(ListView):
    model = TermsConditions
    template_name = "home/terms.html"
    context_object_name = "terms"

class PrivacyView(ListView):
    model = PrivacyPolicy
    template_name = "home/privacy.html"
    context_object_name = "policys"

class ContactView(generic.FormView):
    form_class = ContactForm
    template_name = "home/contact.html"

    def get_success_url(self):
        return reverse("contact")

    def form_valid(self, form):
        """"Getting clean data from the form and creating
        a message to get sent to default email."""
        messages.success(self.request,
                         "Thank you for getting in touch with us. We have received your message.")
        name = form.cleaned_data.get('name')
        email = form.cleaned_data.get('email')
        message = form.cleaned_data.get('message')

        full_message = f"""
        Received Message/Comment below from: 
        Name: {name}
         
        Email: {email},
        ___________________________
        Message/Comment: 
        {message}

        """
        send_mail(
            subject="Message/Comment from Webpage contact form",
            message=full_message,
            from_email=settings.DEFAULT_FROM_EMAIL,
            recipient_list=[settings.NOTIFY_EMAIL]
        )
        return super(ContactView, self).form_invalid(form)
```

Django Error page:
[image: Django Error page]

All apps error page:
[image: All apps error page]

Comment: Your `views.IndexView` is trying to access a Delivary model and get some instance and is failing to do so. Does you template `"home/index.html"` make use of `Delivary` model?

Comment: @MuslimbekAbduganiev Hi, It doesn't directly, but the Delivery models is requested in the global context. from the bag app.

Comment: @MuslimbekAbduganiev Thank you, you pointed me in the right direction, my modal was not loaded properly. Many Thanks

Comment: @ClintonDavis could you elaborate on the error and how you fixed it, possibly by adding an answer?